# I need to check CHAR Fields for numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints

How do I do a check of fields in a `table` to verfiy that the `CHAR(X)` field contains only numbers, `not NULL`, and has X digits and returns a specific `error` for each fault?
Anything I can think of is very clunky.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TRY_CONVERT` for data validation where the syntax checks for null like

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(int,'21245')
```

Something like below may help match fields that are incorrect

```
SELECT * FROM  Table_1 where LTRIM(RTRIM(fieldname)) like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: TRY_CONVERT is not available in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

### ResultSet

```
insert into CheckConstraint(Digit)values(1) //Failed

insert into CheckConstraint(Digit)values('ws') //Failed

insert into CheckConstraint(Digit)values(12345) //Passed
```

### For that Your table should be like this to avoid Nullable values

```
CREATE TABLE CheckConstraint
(
  Digit Char(5) Not Null
)
```

### Create a Function

```
Create FUNCTION Validations() RETURNS INT AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @ret INT  = 0 ;
  SELECT @ret = IsNull(COUNT(Digit), 0) FROM CheckConstraint 
  WHERE Digit not like '[0-9]%'
  RETURN IsNUll(@ret, 0);
END;
```

### Constraints to avoid non numeric characters

```
alter TABLE CheckConstraint
  add CONSTRAINT CheckValidations CHECK ((dbo.Validations() = 0));
```

### Constraints to avoid less then or greater then 5 characters

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].CheckConstraint
ADD CONSTRAINT [MinLengthConstraint] CHECK (DATALENGTH(Digit) = 5)
```